# при загрузке php файла на сервере, и доступе к нему - открывается окно сохранения файла в браузере

Tags: php, nginx

Создал тестовый файл php, загрузил на сервер. при доступе по пути, где он должен лежать - открывается окно в браузере предлагающее сохранить этот файл.
на сервере стоит nginx. Вот конф:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/адрес_сайта;
    server_name адрес_сайта;
}
```

на сервере индексный файл лежит именно .html, но нужна возможность использовать php дополнительно

п.с сам php на сервере - установлен

Comment: Теперь осталось подружить nginx и php. Конфигов в инете - валом.

Comment: спасибо
 location ~ \.php$ {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
 }

Comment: более того — образец присутствует прямо в файле `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` в пакете *nginx*, установленном из репозитория дистрибутива *debian* (или любого из его «наследников»).

Comment: Теперь нужно засечь через сколько минут появится вопрос «меня взломали, что делать»

Answer (score 0):

нужно было добавить в конфиг

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

и рестартануть nginx