# скачивание php скрипта вместо его обработки

Tags: nginx, centos, php-fpm

есть виртуальный сервер с centos 7, установлен nginx + php-fpm, не могу настроить конфиг nginx , чтобы при переходе на домен он обрабатывал .php файл, однако при переходе на домен, он предлагает   скачать файл с php скриптом.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  myapptest.gq;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.php;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    #location / {
     #   root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      #  index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    #}

        #location / {
        #   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        #}
    #location ~* ^.+.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        #   access_log        off;
        #   expires           max;
        #}

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root php;
        #fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT    /myapptest.gq;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root php;
        #fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT    /myapptest.gq;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

Comment: [аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/841950/178576)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        root php;
        #fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT    /myapptest.gq;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Так и что вебсервер передаёт и кому? Сетевой пасс закоментирован, обращение к сокету тоже. Соотв. енджинкс отдаёт то, что и получает из файла на входе, работая по сути, как "сервер для выдачи статики"