# Проблема с запуском nginx на Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-nginx

Установил nginx на ноутбук с ОС Ubuntu 20.04, сделал базовую настройку. Захотел протестировать: создал файл `index.php` и написал базовую структуру.

Ввожу в адресную строку `localhost`, и вместо того чтобы отображать страницу, этот файл сохраняется на мой ноутбук. Если переименовать в `index.html`, то всё работает.

Не знаю, в чём может быть проблема.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [обработка скачивание php скрипта вместо его обработки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/983043/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-php-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: и вдогонку http://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html

Comment: [аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/841950/178576)

Answer (score 1):

Все просто. Базовая настройка (непонятно что это, но видимо настройки по умолчанию) не подразумевает обработку скриптов. Это просто отображение содержимого. Именно поэтому HTML-файл у вас отображается нормально, а при попытке открыть PHP - он скачивается как файл.

Вам необходимо добавить интерпретатор PHP в систему, который и будет обрабатывать код в скриптах, выдавая уже результат nginx. Для PHP таких способов несколько, иногда ставят еще Apache + PHP-MOD, на другой порт его вешают и соответственно nginx передает управление этой связке при запросах на php-файл . Иногда ставят PHP-FPM, таким образом потом nginx просто передает php на выполнение в интерпретатор php-fpm.

Если у вас это просто локальная разработка скриптов, то вполне хватит связки Nginx + PHP-FPM через fastcgi. Такая связка требует меньше памяти, чем с прослойкой в виде Apache, работает вполне стабильно. А так как у вас Ubuntu, то можно связать через сокеты, что тоже добавит быстродействия. У меня есть сервер, который на 512МБ ОЗУ держит несколько простых сайтов на Drupal именно на такой связке и этого вполне хватает. Ссылку на настройку давать не буду, обычное гугление выдаст множество статей по этой теме, выбирайте любое на вкус (например с DO).

Есть только одна тонкость - такая связка не умеет обрабатывать .htaccess файлы, поэтому если для какого-то движка или по какой то инструкции такое понадобится, вам эти правила придется переписывать в конфиг nginx для хоста. Благо это в целом не сильно сложно и есть множество инструкций и готовых примеров в сети. Или добавьте Apache.

Comment: Оффтоп. @Softovick, а ты на juick.com случайно не сидел одно время?

Comment: Да, сидел и ник мне твой знаком :)